# control template in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms, partial-views

Previous to MVC, when webforms was the only thing we had, I used to define a container for my controls (A Box you may call) and used this web control (with title, body and a couple of other properties) in other controls.

So if I wanted to change the look of all my visual controls, I just had to make one change in my Box control.

Here's a simplified snippet of what I used to do:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Box.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApp.Controls.Box" %>
<span class="boxtitle">
    <asp:Literal ID="ltrTitle" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</span>
<div class="boxContent" id="dvBox">
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="BoxBodyContainer"/>
</div>
```

And in code-behind:

```
public Control BoxBody { get; set; }
public string Title
{
    get { return this.ltrTitle.Text; }
    set { this.ltrTitle.Text = value; }
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BoxBodyContainer.Controls.Add(this.BoxBody);
}
```

So I could use this along with other controls in my page as follows:

```
<MyControls:Box ID="Box1" Title="Foo" runat="server">
    <boxbody>
        <MyControls:CustomControl ID="Bar" runat="server" >
         </MyControls:CustomControl>
    </boxbody>
</MyControls:Box>
```

In order to have something alike in MVC 3, I think I should define a `Box` view and wherever I need the box, use `Html.Partial` or `Html.Action` and pass all my data (title, boxbody, etc) to this view and use `@Html.Raw` in Box view.
But I was wondering if there's any better, more standard way to achieve this.
What's the correct way of achieving this in MVC 3 (Razor)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an Html Helper extension method to do this. [The best tutorial I could find was for MVC2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs), but it gives you the basics.

What the tutorial doesn't cover is that there are classes in the `System.Web.MVC` namespace that can help you create html in code.

**Note:** The following code hasn't been tested.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Box(this HtmlHelper helper, string title, MvcHtmlString body)
    {
        TagBuilder span = new TagBuilder("span");
        span.AddCssClass("boxtitle");
        span.SetInnerText(title.ToString());

        TagBuilder div = new TabBuilder("div");
        div.AddCssClass("boxContent");
        div.InnerHtml = body;

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(span.ToString() + div.ToString());
    }
}
```

You can call this method from the razor view like so:

```
@Html.Box("foo", Html.Partial("bar"))
```

Comment: Thanks. This is probably the best way.